# java.util.Optional with java.lang.Class - strange behaviour

Tags: java, eclipse, class, generics, java-8

I tried to do the following:

```
Class<?> clazz = Optional
        .ofNullable(settingsMap.get(key))
        .map(Object::getClass)
        .orElse(DBObject.class);
```

Eclipse shows an error on `orElse`: "`The method orElse(Class<capture#12-of ? extends Object>) in the type Optional<Class<capture#12-of ? extends Object>> is not applicable for the arguments (Class<DBObject>)`".

Then I tried the following, which **works**:

```
Optional<Class<?>> opClazz = Optional
        .ofNullable(settingsMap.get(key))
        .map(Object::getClass);
Class<?> clazz = opClazz.orElse(DBObject.class);
```

Have I done something wrong? Or is this a bug in Java8?

--

### EDIT: Complete example:

```
Map<String, Object> settingsMap = new HashMap<>();

Class<?> clazz = Optional
        .ofNullable(settingsMap.get(""))
        .map(Object::getClass)
        .orElse(String.class);
```

Comment: Hm, seems to work using javac (not eclipse). How is your `settingsMap` defined?

Comment: It's just `Map<String, Setting<?>> settingsMap = new HashMap<>();`.

Comment: Definitely an `Eclipse` issue.

Answer (score 3):

This one (below) works well in IntelliJ:

```
    Map<String, Class<?>> settingsMap = new HashMap<>();

    Class<?> clazz = Optional
            .ofNullable(settingsMap.get(""))
            .map(Object::getClass)
            .orElse(DBObject.class);
```

Are you sure it is not Eclipse's own compiler failing?

Comment: See my comment above, it a `Map<String, Setting<?>>`.